# Do Persian Jews voice Hebrew ק?

Tags: english, hebrew, voicing, transliteration, persian

I recently saw the Hebrew name יעקב transliterated into (American) English by Persian Jews as *Yaghob*. I find this curious (because the ע isn't transliterated, but that's a question for another time, and) because the ק, which afaik is voiceless, is transliterated *gh*. Do Persian Jews pronounce Hebrew ק voiced? If so, how did that come to be? If not, why might they transliterate יעקב with *gh* in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name Jacob is well-known among Jews, Christians and Muslims. In Iran this name is known in all communities in the Arabic/Qurʼanic form Yaʻqūb يعقوب but in Persian the Arabic letter q ق is pronounced as a fricative /γ/. The Arabic ʻ ع is silent in Persian.